# Pointer in a pair in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, std-pair

I need to return an array and it's size:

```
pair<int*, int> load(string path,int * memory){
    ifstream handle;
    int container;
    int size = 0; 

    if(!handle){
        QMessageBox::warning(0, QString(""), "file cannot be loaded");
        return make_pair(NULL,-1);
    }

    handle.open(path.c_str());
    while(!handle.eof()){
        handle >> container;
        size++;
    }
    size--;
    if(!size){
        QMessageBox::warning(0, QString(""), "file is empty");
        return make_pair(NULL,-1);
    }
    memory = new int[size]; 

    handle.clear();
    handle.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        handle >> memory[i];
    }
    handle.close();
    return make_pair(memory, size);
}
```

The error output is:

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:109: error: invalid conversion
>   from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

How do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to "C++ for the gentleman of class". May we interest you in our shiny `std::vector`s? They even know their own size! Guaranteed leak- and weather-proof.

Comment: But your question evaporates if you use vectors. Also, you have a massive `eof()` error in your code.

Comment: Everything. Literally. Search this site for thousands of questions with the same problem, or just stick around for half a day. There's basically no correct way to use `eof()`, and people who use it *always* get it wrong.

Comment: Question about `eof`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: My bad. And what is the problem? The eof seems to have worked out for me.

Comment: Well, your code isn't serious. The `container` variable is just dead. It would be undefined behaviour to read it, though.

Comment: Well, i can't argue about it. I am a naive writer

Comment: @KerrekSB There are correct ways of using `eof()`.  But only once you've determined that the input has failed. (If `eof()` and `bad()` aren't true, after failure, you have a format problem.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: That's true (and a good example of what it's useful for!), and I used to be more reserved in the way I phrased this. But in my experience since, anyone who posts on SO and uses `eof()` does it for the wrong reasons and in the wrong way. Presumably, once you were deliberately trying to tell formatting problems from end-of-input, you would already have bothered to read up the manual on what all those status bits do! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since NULL is probably defined as:

```
#define NULL 0
```

the expression `make_pair(NULL,-1)` becomes `make_pair(0, -1)`, so it creates `pair<int, int>`. You can for example use `nullptr` if available or `(int*)NULL` otherwise.

Comment: @KerrekSB Because `nullptr` is C++11, and most people can't count on C++11 yet.